# Sed: Trying to translate searched group into shell execution to format output

Tags: bash, sed, scripting

I am trying to write a script that will be doing some log highlighting for some human readability. Issue I am running into is trying to match a wildcard while also trying to print the wildcard variable. In my file I am searching for "psuslot-*" (can be either 1 or 2). The goal is to highlight the string "psuslot-1" or "psuslot-2" in the line of the log. My current command I am testing with is:

`cat file.txt | sed "s|\(psuslot-.\)|$(printf "\033[93m"\1"\033[0m")|"`

Highlights this in the output: `1`

I know the groups are relatively correct as this command retains the correct group:

`cat file.txt | sed "s|\(psuslot-.\)|\1|"`

Retained in the output: `psuslot-1` and `psuslot-2`

Using capture groups does not look to translate well into the shell execution. Is there a way to translate the wildcard into the execution?

Comment: Why don't you use grep? Most distros have builtin coloring

Comment: Yeah, `grep --color=always psuslot-. file.txt` would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
sed 's|\(psuslot-.\)|\o33[93m\1\o33[0m|'
```

or less readable

```
sed 's|\(psuslot-.\)|'$(printf '\033[93m')'\1'$(printf '\033[0m')'|'
```

I have taken the syntax for the octal value from the GNU sed manual: [Escape Sequences - specifying special characters](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Escapes.html)

> `\oxxx`
>   Produces or matches a character whose octal ASCII value is xxx.

And `\o033` produced the same result as `\o33` (same as hexadecimal `\x1b`), so I took the shorter one.

Comment: Upvoted, but I think we would benefit from an explanation of the \o33 in the first command :)

Comment: @Quasímodo Added.